# How to use BsonDocument to filter document by dates

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using BsonDocument to get documents from mongDB. i need to add multiple conditions to do that.

I have added one filter and I need to another filter to get latest data (last 7 days )

I'm trying to add below code and dont know how to set condition

```
 List<TestDataObject> returnResult = new List<TestDataObject>();
            BsonDocument filter = new BsonDocument();
            Links links = new Links();
            try
            {
                filter.Add("EvaluationComplete", new BsonBoolean(isEvaluated));
                filter.Add("DateRunUtc", new BsonDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)),condition);
                var options = new FindOptions<BsonDocument>()
                {
                    Skip = skip,
                    Limit = limit
                };

                long count = await _testResultCollection.CountDocumentsAsync(filter);

                links = GetHATEOAS(count, skip, limit, hateoasUrl, "TestResult");

                using (var cursor = await _testResultCollection.FindAsync(filter, options))
                {
                    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                    {
                        var batch = cursor.Current;
                        foreach (BsonDocument document in batch)
                        {
                            TestDataObject testData = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestDataObject>(document);
                            testData.Self = self + "/self?id=" + testData.Id;
                            returnResult.Add(testData);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out

```
  filter.Add("DateRunUtc", new BsonDocument("$gte", new BsonDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))));
```

Comment: With MongoDb you can also associate some strong types to each collection and use the MongoDb Query API. For your example you could do something like this:FilterDefinitionBuilder<TEntity> filterBuilder = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<TEntity>(); filterBuilder.And(filterBuilder.Gte<DateTime>((entity) => entity.Created, CreatedBiggerThen), filterBuilder.Lte<DateTime>((entity) => entity.Created, CreatedlessThen)); where your TEntity is some time with constraints that needs to have some date fields.

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDb you can also associate some strong types to each collection and use the MongoDb Query API. For your example you could do something like this:

```
FilterDefinitionBuilder<TEntity> filterBuilder = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<TEntity>();

var dateIntervalQuery = filterBuilder.And(filterBuilder.Gte<DateTime>((entity) => entity.Created, CreatedBiggerThen), filterBuilder.Lte<DateTime>((entity) => entity.Created, CreatedlessThen));
```

where your TEntity is some time with constraints that needs to have some date fields.
the CreatedLessThen and CreatedBiggerThen will be the fields wich you want to compare with.

Take this for example: https://github.com/vpaulino/VPFrameworks/blob/master/src/VPFrameworks.Persistence.MongoDb/MongoDbRepository.cs